# add number after clicking button

Tags: php, button, numbers

I am new to php. so I am facing some difficulty to create a button. button means if somebody clicks on button then 50 points will add to his account. then his account has 50points. if he click again then his account will be 100points.but i don't know how to put that in code.

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <form method="POST">
            <button name="hey">submit</button>
            <p id="demo"></p>
            <?php if (isset($_POST['button']))  { 
              $severname = "localhost";
              $user = "";
              $password = "";
              $database = ""; 
              $con = mysqli_connect("$severname", "$user", "$password" , "$database"); 
            ?> 
            <script> 
                var first = 20;
                var last = 90;
                var sum = first + last; 
                document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sum;                
            </script>
            <?php  }?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

i am very new to php

Comment: Show us what have you tried till now

Comment: You can surely give it a go though? Just have the button submit a form (don't need any form fields or anything) to a php script that adds 50 points to the currently logged in user (assume you have a login thing up and running)

Comment: Where is "his account"? Is this some client side operation or server side?

Comment: it has but I didn't mention it here  @curiousBoy

Comment: Is it always going to add 50? If so, then why you don't just submit the page and everytime it hits the server, update the record in db. You can directly update its value with query to increment by 50, or you can pull the record from db first, then add 50 on top of it, then save it to db. Based on your purpose, all you need to is hitting the server when the page is submitted. And to be able to submit the page, just use <input type="submit">

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I get your question, but hope this helps.

Also you might want to check [PHP Update Data in MySQL](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp) and [PHP 5 Form Handling](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp) and [PHP 5 Complete Form Example](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp) link to learn more about the basics

```
 <html>
        <body>
            <form action="YOUR_PAGE.php" method="get">
                Points to Add:
                <input type="text" name="points">
                <br> 
                <input type="submit">
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

And in your action page, in this case it is YOUR_PAGE.php, just get the value like below:

```
<?php $points =  $_GET["points"]; 
mysql_query("
    UPDATE member_profile 
    SET AccountPoints = AccountPoints  + ".$points."
    WHERE user_id = '".$userid."'
"); 

?>
```

Or you can pull the record from db, add 50 on it, then save it. Or directly update the db like above.

Note: In the example, I just used whatever user entered the text box. If you always want to add 50, then you don't even need that text box. Just add 50 directly.